# Pull log of a constant out of an integral

Tags: logarithms

Can you pull the log of a constant out of an integral?

Can the integral of ln(x/5)•dx become the integral of ln(x)•dx - ln(5) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\ln\frac xa~dx=\int\big(\ln x-\ln a\big)~dx=\int\ln x~dx-\int\ln a~dx=x\big(\ln x-1\big)-x\ln a.$$